# Amazon Api: get order refund status

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am using amazon mws api on one of my project and now need to get status of orders, I got shiped, unshiped statuses now to need to get refund status.
Can you guide me which api and which api part I need to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the **MWS Finances API** response. You should find `FinancialEvents` and `RefundEventList` there.

Or check **Reports API**. MWS Finances API will give you ability to compute the refund.